# If no tr, hide table

Tags: jquery, html

I'm outputting this table:

```
<table class="table-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Location</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Eta Fix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I need the entire table to not display if the tbody is empty as above

Tried using variations on this:

```
$(function(){
  if ($('.table-example > tbody').length == 0){
    $('.table-example).hide();
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your looking for the number of tbody elements there are inside of .table-example instead of tr elements. Change the selector to ".table-example > tbody tr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
  if ($(".table-example > tbody > tr").length == null || $(".table-example > tbody > tr").length == 0){
    $(".table-example").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-example">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Location</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th scope="col">Status</th>
    <th scope="col">Eta Fix</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use `:has` selector or method along with `:empty` selector

```js
$('.table-example').has('tbody:empty').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-example">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Location</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th scope="col">Status</th>
    <th scope="col">Eta Fix</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

  if ($('.table-example > tbody > tr').length == 0){
    $('.table-example').hide();
  }

});
```

You can use `.table-example > tbody > tr` and you are missing ' in `$('.table-example').hide();`.
I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The selector  $('.table-example > tbody') will return a length of one if there is a tbody tag in the table at all. Instead you need to check for any elements within tbody:

```
$(function(){
  if ($('.table-example tbody *').length == 0){
    $('.table-example).hide();
  }
});
```